# Federated table/query not working - "Cannot read in location: us-west1"

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a GCS bucket in `US-WEST1`:

[image]

That bucket has two files:

1. wiki_1b_000000000000.csv.gz
2. wiki_1b_000000000001.csv.gz

I've created a external table definition to read those files like so:

[image]

The dataset where this external table definition exists is also in the `US`.

[image]

When I query it with:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `grey-sort-challenge.bigtable.federated`
LIMIT
  100
```

..I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot read in location: us-west1

[image]

I tested with `asia-northeast1` and it works fine.

Why isn't this working for the US region?

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same earlier. See G's answer - must use us-central1 for now: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76127552#comment11

Comment: Docs state: _"For example, if you are creating an external table in a US-based dataset, the Cloud Storage bucket containing the data must be a regional or multi-regional bucket in the US."_ . No mention of zones. So, either the docs are wring or this is a bug? (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage)

Comment: I agree that this requirement should be clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: Still an issue in Oct 2021

Answer (score 1):

*For people from Europe*

If you get an error `Cannot read in location: EU` while trying to read  from external source - regional GCS bucket, you have to place your data in region `europe-west1` as per [the same comment](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#data-locations). Unfortunately it is not reflected in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations) yet.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to create a federation(external table) to contiually load up data from a new csv file which was imported each day.

In attempting to do so I was getting "Error: Cannot read in location: xxxx "

I solved the problem by:

1. I recreated a NEW bucket, this time select the US ( Multiple regions )
2. I then went back to BIG query and created a NEW data set with the data location as United States (US)

Presto!, I am now able to query an (constantly updating) external table!